# Arrays.asList Cannot access class in same package

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm following a Spring Boot tutorial with 2 simple classes. This is the controller class:

```java
package org.example.springbootquickstart.topic;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicController {

   @RequestMapping( "/topics" )
   public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
      return Arrays.asList(
            new Topic("123123123", "Spring Framework", "Spring Framework Description"),
            new Topic("java", "Core Java", "Core Java Description"),
            new Topic("javascript", "JavaScript", "JavaScript Description"));
   }
}
```

This is the Topic class:

```java
package org.example.springbootquickstart.topic;

public class Topic {

   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String description;

   public Topic() {

   }

   public Topic( String id, String name, String description ) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
   }

// getters and setters ...

}
```

The main class is in the package `org.example.springbootquickstart`. Now, this code runs without any issues, I can see the JSON response when opening the route:

[image]

The issue is that IntelliJ shows the following error message and I can't figure out why this is the case:
`Cannot access org.example.springbootquickstart.topic.Topic`

[image]

Comment: Based on your description, it should work.
Can you share the Project? You can upload it using https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the upload ID.
Also make sure you are running the latest version of IDE and try File | Invalidate caches... | Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Trying to upload the file solved the issue. I'll add an answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with where I saved the project on the system. By mistake, I saved it in the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects\.idea` instead of `C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects\`

After moving the project there are no more issues and automatically rebuilding works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Reload files from disk'/'Reload project'/'Invalidate caches'. Sometimes Intellij shows errors like that without any reason

Comment: I also assume that this is some IntelliJ issue. Unfortunately this didn't help. It's very annoying because the setting "Build project automatically" also doesn't work and I think it's because of the error message. This means that I have to run maven clean install every time I do a code change...

Comment: Those two issues are definitely related and I suggest you focus on "Build project automatically" not working, because that's more likely to be the root cause.